# Changing status bar color on button click - iOS

Tags: ios, colors, statusbar

If I were wanting to change the status bar's color from white to black when I click a button, how would I do that? I'm not using this for a app or any practical purpose but I just want to see how it would look.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change your status bar appearance from  `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`

on button click call below method ->

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

For that to work
you have to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` as `NO` in app plist keys.